# Breaking strings in an array into subarrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

Doing the DNA challenge and so close but clearly misunderstanding `prototype.split("")`. What's the best way to turn these strings `["AC", "CA", "TA"]` into subarrays? `[["A","C"]["C","A"]["T","A"]]`

```js
function pairElement(str) {
  //break into array
  var arr = str.split("");

  //add new letter (could be refactored as switch)
  for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] == "G") {
      arr[i] += "C";
    } else if (arr[i] == "C") {
      arr[i] += "G";
    } else if (arr[i] == "T") {
      arr[i] += "A";
    } else if (arr[i] == "A") {
      arr[i] += "T";
    }
  }

  //break into arrays again
  //this is how I'm trying to use.split to break it up. Doesn't work.
  var broken = [];
  for (x = 0; x < arr.length; x++) {
    broken += arr[x].split("");
  }

  //return
  return arr;
}

console.log(pairElement("GCG"));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually have to just push the split result in the broken array and return it !

```js
function pairElement(str) {
  //break into array
  var arr = str.split("");

  //add new letter (could be refactored as switch)
  for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] == "G") {
      arr[i] += "C";
    } else if (arr[i] == "C") {
      arr[i] += "G";
    } else if (arr[i] == "T") {
      arr[i] += "A";
    } else if (arr[i] == "A") {
      arr[i] += "T";
    }
  }

  //break into arrays again
  //this is how I'm trying to use.split to break it up. Doesn't work.
  var broken = [];
  for (x = 0; x < arr.length; x++) {
    broken.push(arr[x].split(""));
  }

  //return
  return broken;
}

console.log(pairElement("GCG"));
```

Comment: This may not be the neatest syntax but you get the answer because you're totally right yaaaaay! Thank you!

Comment: Well the point is for you to understand where the problem is ! and from there you can optimize your code!

Answer (score 3):

you can use [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) them by `""`

```js
var o =  ["AC", "CA", "TA"];

var s =  o.map(e=> e.split(""));

console.log(s)
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer your 'what's the best way' question, map your arrays into the split versions of themselves:

```
const subarrays = array.map(pair => pair.split());
```

Answer (score 1):

Very simple in functional style:

```
> seq = ['AC', 'CA', 'TA']
[ 'AC', 'CA', 'TA' ]
> seq.map(s => s.split(''))
[ [ 'A', 'C' ], [ 'C', 'A' ], [ 'T', 'A' ] ]
```

Comment: Good to see a clean way of doing this. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Overall, I'd do some refactoring on the whole function:

```js
var m = new Map([["G", "C"], ["C", "G"], ["A", "T"], ["T", "A"]]);

function pairElement(str) {
  return [...str].map(c => [c, m.get(c)]);
}

console.log(pairElement("GCG"));
```

---

And if there's a guarantee that the sub-arrays are ***never*** mutated, then you can save a good bit of memory by reusing arrays instead of creating them over and over.

```js
var m = new Map([["G", ["G", "C"]], ["C", ["C", "G"]], ["A", ["A", "T"]], ["T", ["T", "A"]]]);

function pairElement(str) {
  return [...str].map(c => m.get(c));
}

console.log(pairElement("GCG"));
```

---

But to directly answer your question, you can do it without explicit `.split()` calls. Since you know there's always two characters, you can use parameter destructuring on the strings.

```js
var arr = ["AC", "CA", "TA"];

var s = arr.map(([a, b]) => [a, b]);

console.log(s)
```

---

Or even a little shorter using rest syntax, like this:

```js
var arr = ["AC", "CA", "TA"];

var s = arr.map(([...a]) => a);

console.log(s)
```

---

Or using spread syntax in an array literal:

```js
var arr = ["AC", "CA", "TA"];

var s = arr.map(s => [...s]);

console.log(s)
```